# Lxterminal open several tabs from shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal

Im trying to open several tabs in a shell script. In gnome-terminal it looks like that:

```
gnome-terminal \
--tab -e "bash -ic \" echo 'First tab' "; exec bash\"" \
--tab -e "bash -ic \"echo 'Second tab' "; exec bash\""
```

Im trying to do in lxterminal but it doesnt work :(

```
lxterminal \
--tabs  -e "bash -ic \" echo 'First tab'; exec bash\"" \
--tabs  -e "bash -ic \" echo 'Second tab'; exec bash\"" \
```

in a help file I see:

```
Usage:
  lxterminal [Options...] - LXTerminal is a terminal emulator

Options:
  -e, --command=STRING             Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal
  --geometry=COLUMNSxROWS          Set the terminal's size
  -l, --loginshell                 Execute login shell
  -t, -T, --title=,
    --tabs=NAME[,NAME[,NAME[...]]] Set the terminal's title
  --working-directory=DIRECTORY    Set the terminal's working directory
  --no-remote                      Do not accept or send remote commands
  -v, --version                    Version information
```

Comment: why is it an offtopic?! It is a clear problem how to open tabs in lxterminal using shell code...

Comment: is somebody going to answer me please?

Answer (score 2):

Just to open tabs, you can use
`lxterminal --tabs="First tab","Second tab"`

But i'm not sure that you can execute something in them

P.S. Usually I'm using `tmux` or `byobu` inside of any terminal emulator for tabs and other comfortable features